# Swift 2.0: Variable was never mutated, consider changing it to let

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

After converting my source code to Swift 2.0, I have got 999+ warnings out of which more than 500 warnings will be "Variable abc was never mutated, consider changing it to let". Is there a way to fix all these warnings at a single shot? Going line by line and fixing this warning takes huge time.

Atleast Apple should have automatically updated while converting to Swift 2.0.

Comment: Or the developer could have use the correct mutability in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could search and replace all occurrences of `var` with `let` and see if that returns fewer errors.

There is no *optimize* functionality if that is what your are looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a thought: Globally change all `var` to `let` and then revert the errors, my guess is that there will be fewer to change.

Answer (score 2):

at least you can use the Fix all in Scope functionality of xcode to batch convert the variables to constants (Editor -> Fix all in scope)